HIVE SQL script to set end date to 12-31 of current year
I need help with a query that when criteria is met to update an end date to 12-31 of the current year.
In addition, the format would need to be: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
I would like to automate this as opposed to forcing a '2024-12-31' date, then having to change the code again in 2025, 2026,...
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

This resolution did help me with my case statement:
THEN date_format(to_date('2024-12-31'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
ELSE appl_support_end_date
END     as appl_support_end_date

